# NSolve unable to solve implicit differentiation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, calculus

I'm trying to solve for the slope with this implicit differentiation problem at x=1, but NSolve is unable to solve it. How can I get around this issue?

```
eqn[x_, y_] := x*Sin[y] - y*Sin[x] == 2 (*note: bound is -5<=x<=5,-5<=y<=5*)

yPrime = Solve[D[eqn[x, y[x]], x], y'[x]] /. {y[x] -> y, 
y'[x] -> y'} // Simplify
{{Derivative[1][y] -> (y Cos[x] - Sin[y])/(x Cos[y] - Sin[x])}}

NSolve[eqn[x, y] /. x -> 1, y] (*this doesn't work*)
```

Comment: why do you define `yPrime` then not use it? Where is the "implicit differentiation"? Unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

`NSolve` is not really the right tool for the job.

From [Wolfram Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalEquationSolving.html)

> If your equations involve only linear functions or polynomials, then
>   you can use `NSolve` to get numerical approximations to all the
>   solutions. However, when your equations involve more complicated
>   functions, there is in general no systematic procedure for finding all
>   solutions, even numerically. In such cases, you can use `FindRoot` to
>   search for solutions. You have to give `FindRoot` a place to start its
>   search.

Since your function is not really polynomial the following works :

```
FindRoot[eqn/.x->1,{y,-2}]
{y -> -2.7881400978783035` }
```

which you can plug into `yprime`.

Picking the starting point is not evident, however making a quick `ContourPlot` always works:

```
ContourPlot[x*Sin[y] - y*Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Contours -> {2}]
```

It shows that your equation is not unique for all `x`.